# Scheme genetic algortihm

Tags: scheme, racket, genetic-algorithm, knapsack-problem

I have started to use Scheme in many different things, right now I have been assigned a task that implement a genetic algorithm just for complete the training. I took the knapsack algorithm as the one that I have to develop, so is there a way to start to figured out how do I have to implement it?

If there is an example somewhere of this algorithm on scheme I would be very grateful to have the link.

Thanks.